# What are the policies for accepting meta answers?

Tags: discussion, meta

I've been asking some meta questions lately, but I'm not sure when a meta answer should be accepted.

Since the decisions made in these posts affect the entire site, it doesn't really feel right for me, the OP, to pick which answer should be accepted.

Even if there is an answer which I personally agree with, should I wait until the question has a decent number of views? (if so, what qualifies as a "decent number"?)

Are there any existing policies around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "policy", *per se.* Accepting an answer is a completely voluntary and optional activity and it may not apply to all situations.

The 'accepted answer' isn't really intended for one user to select which answer is "correct"; the purpose of the 'accepted answer' is to indicate which post you found most helpful, personally. If the original premise of your post doesn't really fit the 'accepted answer' model, I would simply ignore it. No need to force it into a use case that doesn't fit.

Comment: With that in mind, I'll now accept this answer (even though this post only has 6 views) ;)